# How to cross-fade a UIScrollView back to the beginning

Tags: ipad, uiview, core-animation, transition

I have a horizontally-scrolling paging UIScrollView in an iPad app, containing lots of pages. On the last page, I tap on a button on the screen to reset back to page 1. I would like to be able to cross-dissolve this transition, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{
    pagingScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self refreshPages];
}];
```

I read that adding `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` will allow all content to transition, but it doesn't work. Instead, the screen cross-dissolves to the background colour, and when the transition is complete, the first page just appears.

Comment: I don't think AllowAnimatedContent is necessary here because you don't need property-based animation to occur during the transition. By the way you could also try setting the content offset using setContentOffset:animated: to explicitly disable the scrolling animation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you cannot fade-out a UIView (the scroller) AND simultaneously fade-in the same view...

you could just using different UIViews...

what you can do is:

1) fadeOut the scroller in the current position (to the backGround)

2) while the scroller is invisible, move it to the right position (with no animation)

3) fadeIn the scroller from the backGround

something like:

```
// START FIRST PART OF ANIMATION
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options: options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{
    pagingScrollView.alpha = 0;


} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

// FIRST PART ENDED
// MOVE SCROLLER (no animation)
    pagingScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;

// START SECOND PART OF ANIMATION
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options: options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{
// fadeIn - animated
    pagingScrollView.alpha = 1;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

// ANIMATION ENDED
    [self refreshPages];
}];



}];
```

**NEW EDIT:**

thanks to amadour, who taught me something with his comments,

i hope he could add an answer of his own, i would vote for him

anyway, to answer to jowie original question:

i got the right animation just moving the contentOffset setting out of the animation block,
and removing UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent (not really needed), and passing pagingScrollView as parameter for transitionWithView

this worked for me:

```
    pagingScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    [UIView transitionWithView:pagingScrollView duration:3.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
//        pagingScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero; // move up, outside of animation block
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"-->> END amimation");
        [self refreshPages];
    }];
```

Comment: That's quite an elegant solution, thanks. Are you sure it's not possible to cross-fade a single view? I thought it worked if you animated the view's frame... Doesn't it use an off-screen render buffer?

Comment: off screen render buffer is used to "freeze" the current screen, so it's faster to render the in-between frames of the animation, but it doesn't render the final frame before of the animation, as far as i know; in general for these kind of animation you set the starting property of a view, then set the final value of that property, and then start the animation, and animation let you see all the in-between values frames; but what you are trying to do is to fadeIn (that is changing the alpha value from 0 to 1) and fadeOut (that is changing same property alpha value from 1 to 0) for same view!

Comment: ...of course you could freeze (=capture the image of the screen) the initial screen by yourself, save it in image, show it on screen over the scrollview, move the scrollview to the final position. at this point you can animate the fadeOut of the captured image, so you get the effect you wanted... search in stackoverflow, there are example for make the screen-capture...

Comment: @meronix Actually, the cross-dissolve UIView transition that Jowie used does exactly this : fade out the previous frame and simultaneously fade in the new frame.

Comment: @amadour: well, not exactly. 
  
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve; 
A transition that dissolves from one view to the next. 

that is: a view disappear while one OTHER appear, not the same view. that's the point... but if you've got code that works, please post it, it would be great

Comment: From the Programming Guide: "the only changes that are normally animated are those associated with showing, hiding, adding, or removing subviews. Limiting animations to this set allows the view to create a snapshot image of the before and after versions of the view and animate between the two images…. However, if you need to animate other changes, you can include the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` option when calling the method. Including that option prevents the view from creating snapshots and animates all changes directly." Still not clear to me what that extra flag does.

Comment: the point is, snapshot or not: the start alpha and the end alpha, for a fadeIn or fadeOut, need to be different (0 to 1 for the fadeIn and 1 to 0 for a fadeOut)... so, we need to set an initial alpha value, and must chose: 1 or 0? and the same for the final step alpha value: 0 or 1? not both value for the same step, of course... said so, we can chose to use the snapshot or not... but the point is that we cannot use the same view for a 1 to 0 alpha AND 0 to 1 alpha changed value...

Comment: @meronix your point is well understood, but the cross-disolve doesn't work by animating the alpha value of the views. Try cross-fading a label text for example: `myLabel.text = @"hello"; [UIView transitionWithView:myLabel duration:5.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{label.text = @"bye-bye;} completion:NULL];` You'll see the label text crossfading nicely though only one view was used.

Comment: @amadour: you're right, then we can manage the goal in jowie question with a transitionWithView, i thought you could use crossDissolve just for fadeIn+fadeOut without changing other properties (like positions or contentOffset...), i'm adding a new edit to my answer. many thanks to you

Comment: @meronix Well done, I did not think of trying to set the contentOffset  before the animation block. Works for me too now.

Comment: That's brilliant! Sorry, I never noticed the update to this post. Works perfectly now, thanks! I'd love to know, though, why this animation works even though it's being fired before the animation block? I'm also surprised that the animation block works at all... I've found that with `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` blocks fire immediately if no valid parameters are tweened.

Comment: :-)  yeah, it seems so magic, right... what i guess is that when we use:     pagingScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;  
before of the animation block, at screen we still have displayed the old contentoffset (until the thread ends and screen refresh its contents), so it take a snapshot of the actual screen, then creates a screenshot of an offscreen bitmap (based on what it knows it will be after the animation), and then cross-fades these 2 screenshots for us

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't received many more upvotes. Great answer -- the edit portion works perfectly.